# Only one Title name displayed on multiple Receipt Items of Receipt Card

Tags: botframework

I am working on the bot framework technology in one of my project and I want to display the Receipt Card following the below link https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html for adding receipt card in my project.

This is my code about Receipt Card.

```
 #region Receipt Card
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            Activity replyToConversation = activity.CreateReply("Welcome to **** Hotels.");
            replyToConversation.Recipient = activity.From;
            replyToConversation.Type = "message";
            replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            //List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
            //cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: "http://cache.*****.com/propertyimages/h/hydcy/hydcy_main02.jpg",alt: "The **** Hyderabad welcomes guests to the heart of the city centre with an array of amenities and comfortable, sophisticated lodging."));
            List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
            CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
            {
                Value = "http://www.*****.com/hotels/travel/hydcy-courtyard-hyderabad/",
                Type = "openUrl",
                Title = "Confirmed"
            };
            cardButtons.Add(plButton);
            ReceiptItem lineItem1 = new ReceiptItem()
            {
                Title = "***** Hyderabad",
                Subtitle = "*****, Hyderabad, IN 500 080",  
                Text= "The **** Hyderabad welcomes guests to the heart of the city centre with an array of amenities and comfortable, sophisticated lodging."
            };
            ReceiptItem lineItem2 = new ReceiptItem()
            {
                Title="Executive Deluxe,Guest Room",
                Image = new CardImage(url: "http://cache.****.com/propertyimages/h/hydcy/hydcy_main02.jpg"),
                Price = "7000.25",
                Quantity = "1",
                Tap = null
            };

            List<ReceiptItem> receiptList = new List<ReceiptItem>();
            receiptList.Add(lineItem1);
            receiptList.Add(lineItem2);

            ReceiptCard plCard = new ReceiptCard()
            {
                Title = "**** Hyderabad Hotel Reservation Confirmed",
                Buttons = cardButtons,
                Items = receiptList,
                Tax = "27.52",
                Total = "7027.77"                                      
            };
            Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
            replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
            var reply = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(replyToConversation);
            #endregion
```

In the above I have added the two Receipt Item’s with different Titles but at the end it was displayed only one title name on two Receipt Item’s in my Receipt Card like this below figure.
[image]

Please tell me, how to resolve the above issue.

I think there may be a bug in Bot Framework Channel Emulator.

-Kishore.

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: I am not using any channel, just i have tested my bot in latest bot emulator.

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Investigating

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for identifying a bug in the emulator.  It has been fixed and should be published shortly.